# Implement find_max

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

The following code gives `error: expansion pattern 'args' contains no parameter packs`

```
template<typename T>
T find_max(T a) {
    return a;
}

template<typename T>
T find_max(T a, T args...) {
    T sofar = find_max(args...);
    if (a > sofar) return a;
    return sofar;
}
```

I found this code snippet

```
T find_max(T a) {
    return a;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T find_max(T a, Ts... args) {
    T sofar = find_max(args...);
    if (a > sofar) return a;
    return sofar;
}
```

However, this does not place any constraint on the type as in `find_max(2, 3, 3.2)` would compile without an error. How can I unpack (if not, how can we use `T args...`) `args` in the first snippet?

Comment: how about [`std::max(std::initializer_list<T>)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T find_max(T a) {
    return a;
}

template<typename T>
T find_max(T a, T b) {
    T sofar = find_max(b);
    if (a > sofar) return a;
    return sofar;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T find_max(T a, T b, Ts... args) {
    T sofar = find_max(b, args...);
    if (a > sofar) return a;
    return sofar;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << find_max(2);
  std::cout << find_max(2, 3);
  std::cout << find_max(2, 3, 4);
  std::cout << find_max(2, 3, 4, 5);
  std::cout << find_max(2, 3, 4, 5.0);  // error: no matching function for call to 'find_max'
}
```

https://ideone.com/LwBdjG

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), and a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) over logical AND:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T find_max(T a) {
    return a;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<Ts, T>), T>
find_max(T a, Ts... args) {
    T sofar = find_max(args...);
    if (a > sofar) return a;
    return sofar;
}
```

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/11f9jxx13)

Comment: Looks great to restrict all Ts to be of the same type. Coming to the second question :  when I have a function parameter pack, `template<typename T, typename... Ts>` `T find_max(T a, Ts... args) {` why can't I unpack `args` ?